# Android Loading a fragment view before launching the fragment. Need review

Tags: android, fragment, android-view

I had a problem with fragment view inflating too slow about 300ms. Rest of the things take about 100ms which it not an issue. That 300ms was bothering me so I Inflated the fragment view in my activity like this.

```
private View testFragment;

public void initTestFragmentLayout() {
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ViewGroup view = findViewById(R.id.mainFrame);
            testFragment = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, view, false);
        }
    });
}
```

And in onCreateView of the fragment

```
 View v = null;
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        v = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getTestFragmentView();
    }
    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    }
```

And in onDestroyView method of the fragment I simply reinitialize the view so I can have a fresh view each time.

```
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).initTestFragmentLayout();
    }
```

The question is Whats the downside of this method? Is it even correct?. And ohh btw my inflate time is down to 0ms. What case could break this code and become an embarrassment for me. Thanks.

Comment: If your fragment is taking too long to inflate i would look at your layouts rather than hack the init of the fragment like this. Look in to data binding for layout inflation too

Comment: I already did the flattening of layouts as much as i could

Comment: post your layout.

Comment: I don't have a problem with layout. It is supposed to take that much time. I just wanted to get a review on above solution.